# MockLLM for VectorStoreIndex from Huggingface

Tags: huggingface, chromadb

I am currently building a small RAG application with a ChromaDB with Huggingface stuff.

It works perfect, but I have a question.

Currently I use this for

```
Settings.llm = MockLLM(max_tokens=256)
Settings.embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbedding(model_name="BAAI/bge-large-en-v1.5")
...
index = VectorStoreIndex(nodes)
```

for my VectorIndex (`Settings` was formerly `ServiceContext` BTW).

The `MockLLM` was from testing, so I wanted to use a production ready llm.

I ran through many examples, tried stuff, but: As it seems, the `Settings.llm` param (former `ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm=llm, ...`) does not make any difference in output / tokenizing / the final vector database.

It's needed to create the `VectorStoreIndex` (when omitting, the Huggingface stuff does use `MockLLM` itself but emits a warning).

Does anybody know if the `llm` makes any difference for a vectordatabase like ChromaDB?